# Error: failed to copy d:\ to c:\win32-loader/linux when trying to install kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I am installing Kali Linux and open the setup file. I continue down the path until it installs the actual thing. Half way through the download it says

> error: failed to copy d:\ to c:\win32-loader/linux

I don't know what this means. Anyone know how to fix this problem?